# How can I get Gmail tab to flash (in Firefox) when I've got a new mail or chat?

Tags: gmail

I'm using Gmail as a fixed tab in Firefox 4 (beta 3), and I'd like the tab to flash when something happens (typically an incoming mail or chat in Gchat).

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

While it isn't a flash, you might try enabling the Gmail Labs "Title Tweaks" item. It will make it very easy for you to spot your unread email count on the tab's title. This is basically how I accomplish what you're after.

As for chat, it seems like sometimes it will update the title as well but I've noticed that doesn't always happen. I don't have a great solution there.

Comment: I use Title Tweaks and I've found it's enough of a visual queue that I have messages. I actually prefer it to a pop-up or flashing notification so I don't keep getting distracted from Real Work to read facebook updates ;)